# bash directly executes overflown characters

Tags: c, bash, file-descriptor

I encountered something weird while trying C read function. I know file descriptor 0 means standard input. So I decided to take input with read function like below

```
 #include<unistd.h>
 int main(){
   char buf[1];
   read(0,buf,1);
   return 0;
 }
```

I compiled that main.c file with gcc

```
$ gcc -o main main.c
```

then I executed `main` binary and then entered input 'tls'. Characters after 't' are interpreted by the shell and output was like the following

```
$ ./main
  tls
$ ls
  main main.c
```

Why the shell directly interprets overflown input characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is overflowed. Your program reads one character from stdin and then exits. Any characters after that are read by the shell.